# Action of Linear Operator on basis of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Say I have a vector space $V$ having basis vectors $\vec{e}_i \text{ for } 1\le i\le n$.

Then, the action of a linear operator $f$ on the basis vectors is given by:
$$f(\vec{e}_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_{ki}\hat{e}_k$$

I wanted to learn the reason behind this definition.

I read some articles on the internet. Some have stated this as a definition, whereas some stated that since $f(\vec{e}_i)$ is in $V$, it should be written as a linear combination of basis vectors which gives the above result.

Can anyone help me out with this confusion?

The related articles:
[http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nearing/mathmethods/operators.pdf](http://www.physics.miami.edu/%7Enearing/mathmethods/operators.pdf) Eqn: 7.6
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/04b0570b349e84d74129eef504498472_MIT8_05F13_Chap_03.pdf Eqn 2.26

Comment: It's the second one. Since $f(v)\in V$ it can be written in an unique way as a linear combination of its basis elements. I don't know any book that defines linear maps as maps acting that way on the basis elements (this is indeed a mathematically correct definition but it's pedagogically and conceptually hideous).

Comment: @Kandinskij But say I have the operator as a $2 \times 3$ matrix which acts on a Three Dimensional Euclidean Vector. The output is a Two Dimensional Euclidean Vector, which is not the same vector space as the input; hence, $f(\vec{e}_i)$ is not in V. Hence, it cannot be written as a linear combination of the input basis. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @SumitGupta letting a $2 \times 3$ matrix $A$ act, defines a linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2: x \mapsto f(x) = A\cdot x$. In your case $e_i = (0,0,1)$ for example and $f(e_i) = Ae_i$ is a vector with two components. Note that this is however not a linear operator: linear operators are linear maps that map a vector space onto itself (so multiplying by $A$ is a linear map, but **not** a linear operator!)

Comment: The numbers $f_{ij}$ are the matrix coefficients of $f$ with respect to the standard basis. When you write a vector $v=v_1\overrightarrow{e_1}+v_2\overrightarrow{e_2}+v_3\overrightarrow{e_3}$ as $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^\top$, then $f(v) = v_1f(e_1)+v_2f(e_2)+v_3f(e_3) = v_1(f_{11}e_1+f_{12}e_2)+v_2(f_{21}e_1+f_{22}e_2)+v_3(f_{31}e_1+f_{32}e_2) = (v_1f_{11}+v_2f_{21}+v_3f_{31})e_1+(v_1f_{12}+v_2f_{22}+v_3f_{32})e_2=\Big(v_1f_{11}+v_2f_{21}+v_3f_{31}\ ,\ v_1f_{12}+v_2f_{22}+v_3f_{32}\Big)$. Compare this to matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you want is that for any set $\{f_{ki} \vert  1 \le i,k \le n \} $of scalars there exists exactly one linear map $f:V \to V$ satisfying your equations. Now you can ask if this theorem can be extended to infinite- dimensional vector spaces and what about modules or free modules or free modules of finite rank over a commutative ring (with identity)?

Comment: Can you add a link to the theorem or any reference where I can read that?

Answer (score 1):

Let your linear transformation be $f:V\to W$ where we are
taking letters $b_1,...,b_n$ for basics of $V$ and $c_1,...,c_m$ for basics on $W$

When you know what a linear transformation is, then
you can assign to basic vector in the domain as your
$$f(b_1)=f_{11}c_1+...+f_{m1}c_m$$
$$f(b_2)=f_{12}c_1+...+f_{m2}c_m$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f(b_n)=f_{1n}c_1+...+f_{mn}c_m,$$
we see how the basis in $V$ is transformed.
These linear combinations exist because the $c_s$ generate $W$.

With this now, it's easy to find how a generic $v\in V$ is transformed,
that is via
$$f(v)=f\left(\sum_sv_sb_s\right)$$
$$=\sum_sv_sf(b_s)$$
$$\quad=\sum_s v_s\left(\sum_t f_{ts}c_t\right)$$
$$=\sum_t \left(\sum_sv_sf_{ts}\right)c_t,$$
place where we can see the components of $f(v)$ in the basis $c_t$ of $W$.

Comment: an important point here, is how the matrices' convention of data is handled

Comment: the best convention allows to see, crystalline clear, how two carry the data to a processing program

Comment: What I meant to ask was, when defining the linear transformation, you took $f_{11}c_1+\cdots+f_{m1}c_m$ where the f's here are clearing the very first column of the transformation matrix. Why the first column why not the first row? The first row would be more intuitive as we are already familiar with matrix multiplication. I guess I'll take the definition as it is for now. Maybe someday later, I might get to know the reason.

Comment: the indexes are set to fit the matrix associated the $f$ as $$[f]=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}f_{11}&f_{12}&\cdots&f_{1n}\\f_{21}&f_{22}&\cdots&f_{2n}\\\vdots&&\ddots&\\f_{m1}&f_{m2}&\cdots&f_{mn}\end{array}\right)$$ being synchronized to see the linear components of $f(b_i)$ in the columns.